# Как правильно задать редактор?

Tags: ubuntu, git, github, gitlab

Вот я работаю с терминалом и когда хочу поверить изменения в гит

```
git diff
```

то он все показывает в терминале

я так понял, что с помощью команды

```
git config --global core.editor "kate"
```

можно установить редактор который будет показывать внесенные изменения

`kate` - это название редактора

После того как я выполнил эту команду я проверил файл `.gitconfig` и там это отобразилось

```
[user]
name = aleksey
email = aleksey@gmail.com
[core]
autocrlf = input
excludesfile = /home/aleksey/.gitexcludes
editor = kate
```

В последней строчке.

Но все равно когда я в терминале набираю `git diff` все открывается в терминале...

Подскажите как это исправить?

Comment: попробуйте `git config diff.tool kate` из ответа на похожий вопрос: [How do I view 'git diff' output with a visual diff program?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/949242/4279) Если работает, то [в виде ответа опубликуйте](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не совсем правильно

Редактор git — это тот редактор, которым вы пишете сообщения коммитов. То есть сейчас если вы запустите `git commit` (`--amend`, если хотите только проверить), то у вас откроется kate для написания коммита.

Если вы хотите посмотреть изменения в каком-то графическом редакторе, то можете перенаправить системными средствами `stdout` в файл и открыть его каким-либо редактором *. Например:

```
git diff > out.txt && kate out.txt
```

** Тут меня должны поправить более компетентные люди, что правильнее смотреть diff-ы в difftool и соответствующих инструментах, отображающие изменения более наглядно, но я не слишком в этом компетентен.*

Можно попробовать запустить `git difftool --tool-help`, который отобразит все возможные (и доступные) для просмотра изменений редакторы (их можно доустановить). Вот пример запуска утилиты `git difftool --tool=vimdiff`

[image: скрин vimdiff]

Конечно же эти редакторы можно установить глобально или на проект (чтобы не писать постоянно `--tool`)